# Composer autoload twig templates

Tags: php, twig, composer-php

Hello everyone I'm making mvc framework and want to use Twig template system installed via commposer. I used this tutorial for 
[MVC](http://blog.oscarliang.net/simple-mvc-framework-tutorial-part-1/) here is my composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": "~1.0"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "files":[
            "config/config.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

when I add `require_once ROOT.'\vendor\autoload.php'` to index.php or bootstrap.php I've got an error:

> 1. File 'items.php' containing class 'ItemsController' might be missing. 2. Method 'index' is missing in 'items.php'

But when I add require_once in library/View.php like this:

```
class View {

    public $loader;
    public $twig;
    public $arg;

    public function __construct() {
        require_once (ROOT.'/vendor/autoload.php');
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(ROOT.'/application/views');
        $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
    }
}
```

It works well where is the problem how to make it works when I add autoload outside View class? All suggestions will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: that tutorial has nothing to do with MVC

Comment: Could you give me a better example of it?

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is using the `__autoload()` function - this makes it incompatible with everything that comes with it's own autoloader, including Composer.

This restriction is due to PHP being unable to allow defining a function twice - so there can be only one autoload function (which was introduced in PHP 5.0). To solve the problem of wanting to add more than one autoloader, everyone starting with PHP 5.1.2 was asked NOT to define `function __autoload()`, but to register a function callback using `spl_autoload_register()`.

PHP 5.1.2 was released in January 2006!

Now think about the quality of an MVC tutorial that doesn't even get autoloading right in 2015 (it got posted in 2013, which doesn't make it better).

In fact, Composer can help you here. You can use it to autoload your own classes as well, but it is easiest if you stick to PSR-4 if you use namespaces, or PSR-0 if you don't (I suggest you do, but that Tutorial does not - another low quality, I'd say).